# D3.js - unable to add lines to a static network

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm not an expert in d3 (as many of you know) however I am attempting to modify a working force network so that the nodes are fixed. So far I have been able to get the nodes to work but haven't been able to get the lines between them to work.

I've created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/PatriciaW/Dnnve/

Any help will be very welcome.

```
var width = 960,
height = 700, 
n = 100;
var categoryColour = {
"community group": "red",
"volunteer": "blue",
"organization": "green",
"air": "transparent"
};
var json2 = {"nodes":[{"node":{"name":"TCAN","x2":1,"y2":2,"description":"A network of organizations in Toronto devoted to climate change mitigation and adaptation.","category":"organization","size":3,"URL":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/mydrupal\/groups\/tcan"}},{"node":{"name":"Rita ","x2":5,"y2":3,"description":"Rita is devoted to mitigating climate change and participates in many organizations.","category":"volunteer","size":2,"URL":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/mydrupal\/groups\/rita"}},{"node":{"name":"Green 13","x2":5,"y2":4,"description":"Green 13","category":"community group","size":2,"URL":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/mydrupal\/groups\/green-13"}},{"node":{"name":"ZCO","x2":3,"y2":1,"description":"Zero Carbon Ontario","category":"organization","size":2,"URL":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/mydrupal\/groups\/zco"}},{"node":{"name":"Resilient Toronto","x2":3,"y2":5,"description":"","category":"organization","size":3,"URL":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/mydrupal\/groups\/resilient-toronto"}},{"node":{"name":"City of Toronto","x2":3,"y2":3,"description":"","category":"organization","size":5,"URL":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/mydrupal\/groups\/city-toronto"}}]};
  var nodes=json2.nodes.map(function(json2) {
    return json2.node;
  }); 
var i = 0;
while (i < nodes.length) {
nodes[i].fixed=true;
nodes[i].x = (nodes[i].x2)*100;
nodes[i].y = (nodes[i].y2)*100;
i = i+ 1;
}
var json = {"connections":[{"connection":{"source":"Rita","target":"Resilient Toronto"}},{"connection":{"source":"TCAN","target":"Resilient Toronto"}},{"connection":{"source":"Resilient Toronto","target":"City of Toronto"}},{"connection":{"source":"Rita","target":"ZCO"}},{"connection":{"source":"Rita","target":"Green 13"}},{"connection":{"source":"Green 13","target":"TCAN"}},{"connection":{"source":"ZCO","target":"TCAN"}}]};
   var links=json.connections.map(function(json) {
    return json.connection;
  });
var force = d3.layout.force()
.nodes(nodes)
.links(links)
.size([width, height])
.linkDistance(60)
.charge(-300)
.on("tick", tick)
.start();

svg = d3.select("#network") 
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(force.links())
.enter().append("line")
.attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "node")
.call(force.drag);

node.append("circle") // this is OK if use nodes or links below but defaults to links
 .attr("r", 8)
 .style("fill", function(nodes) { 
    return categoryColour [nodes.category];
   })     

node.append("text") //  OK
.attr("x", 12)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function(d) { 
    return d.name; });

function tick() {
link
  .attr("x1", function(d) { 
// console.log("d"); console.log(d); has source and target but not .x and y values?
       return d.source.x; })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { 
      return d.source.y; })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { 
     return d.target.x; })
  .attr("y2", function(d) { 
     return d.target.y; });

node
  .attr("transform", function(d) { 
       return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; 
  });
};

// Use a timeout to allow the rest of the page to load first.
setTimeout(function() {

force.tick();
console.log("timeout nodes "); console.log(nodes); // 

svg.selectAll("line")
.data(links)
.enter().append("line")
.attr("x1", function(d) { 
   return d.source.x; })
.attr("y1", function(d) { 
   return d.source.y; })
.attr("x2", function(d) { 
    return d.target.x; })
.attr("y2", function(d) { 
    return d.target.y; });

svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
.attr("r", 4.5);

}, 10);
```

Comment: All you need to do is set the `.fixed` property of all nodes to `true`. Maybe it would be easier to start from a working force layout example?

Comment: I THOUGHT that is what the loop I had added was doing.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You're already doing that -- your question seems to be about the links though. This is why I was suggesting that starting with a working example (i.e. where the links are present) may be easier.

Comment: That is what I did ... but when I look at the Links object there are no x and y attributes which is what is puzzling me. But I will start again as you suggest.

Comment: I was able to get the links working by nesting a loop of the links array with the nodes array and copied the x,y attributes of the source and target nodes to the links array. Not particularly elegant but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert either but I think you are having issues because the source and target values in your connections should be referencing the respective positional array index for the node (not the name of the node).

A simple example, in your fiddle just change the first connection from...

{"connection":{"source":"Rita","target":"Resilient Toronto"}}

to...

{"connection":{"source":1,"target":4}}

1 and 4 being the index of the elements in the nodes array. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I embedded the arrays to be able to demonstrate the problem, but in the real world I am generating them from a Drupal view which is based on two nodes ... one for the members and the others for their relationships. It would be difficult to (maybe impossible) to do this dynamically although I can look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the jsfiddle with the working code. Needs improvement but demonstrates the principle.